# batch file to delete last file in numbered sequence

Tags: batch-file, audio

I'm working on a windows batch script using sox http://sox.sourceforge.net/ to split a folder full of wave files into individual wave files based on silence (there are multiple distinct sounds in each file.)

```
FOR %%f in (*.wav) do (
sox %%f %%f silence 1 0.1 1%% 1 2.5 1%% : newfile : restart)
```

in other words, the folder contains 01.wav, 02.wav etc. and sox outputs 01001.wav 01002.wav, 02001.wav, 02002.wav etc. Because of how sox loops through a wav file I end up with one more file for each original than I should have. I would like to add a loop to the end of my script that determines how many files exist for each initial two digit designator (01, 02, 03) and deletes the last one.

Please let me know if I need to explain this, or if it would be substantially easier in a different scripting language. I saw a reference to someone doing something similiar in perl, but I haven't researched editing wav files in perl yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```dos
for %%f in (*.wav) do (
    sox %%f %%f silence 1 0.1 1%% 1 2.5 1%% : newfile : restart
    set "last=1"
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        dir /a-d /b /o-n "%%~nf*.wav"
    ') do if defined last if not "%%a"=="%%f" ( set "last=" & del "%%a" )
)
```

For each processed input file, a list of `.wav` files with the same name is generated, in descending name order. This list will contain the last generated file (following the naming in question) as the first element, so, this first element (last file in set) is deleted. Aditional check is included to ensure that the original input file is not deleted (just in case the previous file processing did not generate any aditional file).

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%f in (*.wav) do (
   sox %%f %%f silence 1 0.1 1%% 1 2.5 1%% : newfile : restart
   rem Get the last file with this same name plus three digits:
   for %%g in (%%~Nf???.wav) do set "last=%%g"
   del "!last!"
)
```